# OnSelectionChange Not Working Consistently with SpreadsheetApp.getUI().alert("Message") - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This is the most bizarre thing. I have a simple trigger OnSelectionChange function that gives alerts and runs different functions depending on which specified cells are clicked. It was working. Now it's not working. Sometimes if I close the program, swear a lot, and open it again, it will work, sometimes not. It is not working 90% of the time.

In the example below, if you are on the sheet `Units` and you click on the cell range titled `SaveUpdateA1`, it should give the alert "Why is this not working?". Nothing happens. The executions view says "Paused" then eventually says "Timed Out".

**Example**

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName(); //Gets name of sheet where cell was clicked

  //row and column index of active (clicked) cell: 
  var range = e.range; //Activates range of clicked cell
  var rangeA1 = range.getA1Notation(); //Gets A1 notation of clicked cell
  var row = range.getRow(); //Gets row # of clicked cell
  var col = range.getColumn(); // Gets col # of clicked cell
  
  // UNIT SHEET TRIGGERS:
  if(sheet == "Units"){
    var sheetUnits = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Units');
  
    //Variables for Buttons to Save/Update, Add New, Vacate/Archive, and Cancel
    var SaveUpdateA1 = sheetUnits.getRange('O8:O9').getA1Notation(); //A1 notation of Save/Update button
    //Other buttons omitted for this example

    //SAVE/UPDATE BUTTON
    if(rangeA1 == SaveUpdateA1){  
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Why aren't you working?");
    }
```

If I replace the last function in the code above, with the following, it works, albeit pretty slowly:

```
    if(rangeA1 == SaveUpdateA1){  
      sheetUnits.getRange('P2').setValue("Wow");
    }
```

I saw one thread that said it needs to be an installable trigger to use `.getUi().alert()`, but then they said that `onSelectionChange` was not a permissible installable trigger. (I need `onSelectionChange` because I'm simulating clicking buttons).

Another person said that `.getUi().alert()` should work in `onSelectionChange` but it's clearly not in my case.

I would be perfectly happy with an alternative to `.getUi().alert()` if one exists and works consistently with `onSelectionChange`.

Does anyone know how to fix this or use an alternative function? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you are probably running into restrictions https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers either you are trying to do a forbidden thing or you are doing so much you are running into trigger limits. Why aren't you actually using buttons? (You "insert drawing" and then attach a script to it with the hamburger menu). Also more context of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: It is only taking 2.7S to run the above, so I don't think I'm running into the 30 second time limit. I tried replacing the alert function with a toast function and it still doesn't work, whereas the toast works perfectly fine in my onedit triggers. So it must be something to do with onSelectionChange. I don't want to use a button with a drawing because the purpose is to Save/Update a database. If you edit a cell and don't press "Enter" and then click the button drawing, it won't update. All very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the `onSelectionChange()` simple trigger has always worked pretty unreliably. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) tells:

> To activate this trigger, you must refresh the spreadsheet once the trigger is added and every time the spreadsheet is opened. [...]
> If the selection moves between multiple cells in a short time, some selection change events might be skipped to reduce latency.

Star [issue 178615259](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178615259) in the tracker if you would like Google to fix this.

One workaround in your use case would be to use an `onEdit(e)` simple trigger to let you use checkboxes as script runner buttons. See the [checkboxButtons_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/119054769?msgid=120084104) script for sample code.

Comment: The trigger is working according to the execution logs. And in my example with the "wow", it works fine, and in 2.8 seconds. As I mentioned in another comment above, even the toast isn't working. So it seems there is some problem with any type of alert? Do you know if onSelectionChange can be made into an installable trigger? Do you know if that would work on mobile? I'd prefer this over checkboxes since it is cleaner and easier to understand for the user. Thank you

Comment: The `onSelectionChange(e)` simple trigger can do the same stuff that an `onEdit(e)` simple trigger can do. The trouble you mention with `Spreadsheet.toast()` are most likely because your code never runs. Use `console.log()` to verify whether your code runs. Use `onEdit(e)` to make it a bit more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried console.log() and the code is running. I included a toast message after the console.log() as well. The first time I loaded it today, it worked. Every subsequent time, the console.log() message continued to work but the toast stopped working. And when I put in a get.Ui().alert() message, the program timed out. Strangest thing ever.

Answer (score 0):

From observation and extensive experience with the indispensable onSelectionChange trigger: Sometimes after making a change -- any change -- to the onSelectionChange code, the server-side JS engine will freeze up at any Ui-related line of code. If you look at the the Executions log when the freeze happens, you'll see the onSelectionChange trigger Status column will show "Paused", but there will be no message, dialog, nothing displayed over the sheet. After the execution time out period, the log status will show "Timed Out". THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NOTHING YOU CAN DO EXCEPT WAIT. Eventually, (say, a hour or two later), it all starts working again. Is this a bug? YES, it is. Is there a ticket for this? All I could find is this: "https://issuetracker.google.com/178615259 onSelectionChange in Sheets is not working" but that is a different issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is now December 2022 and it still seldom works. I too reported it years ago.

Here is the function I'm trying to use:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
 if (e.range.rowStart != e.range.rowEnd || e.range.columnStart != e.range.columnEnd) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("WARNING", "More than one cell has been selected for editing.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
 }
}
```

It was intended to warn users that they might be going to do something wrong. All I can do now is throw up warnings using function onEdit(e) AFTER they've gone wrong.